# Map modify array of objects in Swift 2.2 (3.0)

Tags: arrays, swift, map-function

I want to be able to modify my array of objects using `map` in Swift of the fly, without looping through each element.

Before here were able to do something like this (Described in more details [here](http://kelan.io/2016/mutating-arrays-of-structs-in-swift/):

```
gnomes = gnomes.map { (var gnome: Gnome) -> Gnome in
    gnome.age = 140
    return gnome
}
```

Thanks for Erica Sadun and others, new proposals have gone through and we're now getting rid of C-style loops and using `var` inside the loop.

In my case I'm first getting a warning to remove the `var` in then an error my `gnome` is a constant (naturally)

My question is : How do we alter arrays inside a `map` or the new styled loops for that matter to be fully prepared for Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to keep that syntax, just use a (mutable) temporary variable

```
gnomes = gnomes.map { (gnome: Gnome) -> Gnome in
  var mutableGnome = gnome
  mutableGnome.age = 140
  return mutableGnome
}
```

Answer (score 18):

*(Below follows the case where `Gnome` is a reference type; a class -- since you haven't showed us how you've defined `Gnome`. For the case where `Gnome` as  value type (a struct), see @vadian:s answer)*

---

The removal of `var` will not effect using `.map` to mutate *mutable* members of an array of *reference* type objects. I.e., you could simply use your old approach (omitting however, the `var` in the `.map` closure signature).

```
class Gnome {
    var age = 42
}

var gnomes = [Gnome(), Gnome(), Gnome()]

gnomes = gnomes.map {
    $0.age = 150
    return $0
}

/* result */
gnomes.forEach { print($0.age) } // 3x 150
```

However, in case you just want to modify your original array rather than assigning the result of `.map` to a new array, `.forEach` might be a more appropriate choice than `.map`.

```
gnomes.forEach { $0.age = 140 }

/* result */
gnomes.forEach { print($0.age) } // 3x 140
```

Comment: returns an error ``$0 is immutable``. It is my fault. I should have been more precise :( I'm using structs instead of classes, I bet that what's make them immutable by default

Comment: @kernelpanic Since you didn't show us you `Gnome` class, I had to include one of my own. Are you certain the `age` property of your class is a mutable one (as well as your array of gnomes)? The above works fine for me on Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.

Comment: @dfri I suspect that `Gnome` is a struct

Comment: Upvoted for the reference to .forEach() this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @jan.vogt happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
struct Gnome {
    var age: Int = 0
}

var gnomes = Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: Gnome())
```

... there are two decent options. The first is as @vadian put it:

```
gnomes = gnomes.map{
    var gnome = $0
    gnome.age = 70
    return gnome
}
```

Whilst the second keeps control over "ageing" `private` and simplifies mapping at the point of call:

```
struct Gnome {
    private(set) var age: Int = 0

    func aged(age: Int) -> Gnome {
        var gnome = self
        gnome.age = age
        // any other ageing related changes
        return gnome
    }
}

gnomes = gnomes.map{ $0.aged(140) }
```

Of course, reference types still have their place in programming, which may well be a better fit in this case. The friction we are experiencing here suggests that we are trying to treat these structures as if they were objects. If that is the behaviour you need, then you should consider implementing `Gnome` as a `class`.