# Modifying a property of each class instance in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview

I have an array containing `UIView` subclass instances, and another array (of the same length) containing `CGPoint`s. Without looping through the arrays, I'd like to assign the `center` property of each `UIView` subclass instance to the (index) associated `CGPoint`.

My first attempt looked something like `UIViewArray.map {$0.center} = CGPointArray`, but I quickly learned that `map` returns a *copy* of the array, so the assignment would be no good. The advice I've been able to find (e.g. [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261710/map-modify-array-of-objects-in-swift-2-2-3-0)) only discusses using `map` for this sort of reassignment when the new parameter values are constant.

What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `UIViewArray` and `CGPointArray` are values, so they should be lowerCamelCase. UpperCamelCase is reserved for type names in Swift. These names don't really communicate anything that isn't obvious from the types. Consider perhaps `views` and `centerPoints`. Their array-ness is implied by the plurality, and the fact that it's `CGPoint` is already clear from the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip(_:_:)) the two together, and mutate the UIViews with either a `for` loop or a `forEach` call.

```
zip(views, centerPoints).forEach { $0.center = $1 }
```